# values of the corners of the div

Tags: jquery

finding the four values of the corners of the div area

Comment: Could you reword your statement into a question? I assume you mean the position of them, relative to what? The browser? The containing div?

Answer (score 2):

relative to the document:

```
var offset = $('#div').offset();
var x1 = offset.left;
var y1 = offset.top;
var x2 = x1 + $('#div').width();
var y2 = y2 + $('#div').height();
```